# What is causing slight steering wheel vibration?

Tags: alignment

My vehicle is a Toyota Grande Mark 2 2001 Model, which slightly vibrates the steering wheel when driving at 100 km/hr or above. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 4):

Steering wheel vibration can be caused by a number of things. Without detail we are unable to say for sure, but here are some likely causes.

1. Tire/Wheel balance
2. Tire condition
3. Wheel alignment
4. Worn steering components

If this vibration is happening when you apply the brakes, then the issue is with the braking system and needs to be serviced.

Answer (score 2):

Don't  forget about wheel bearings and sticky caliper.  I would get first two above done first with a wheel Balance rotation and alognment.